# Temporary upload a file to use it - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, file-upload

I'm trying to get the full path of a file, who is retrieve with an drag and drop. But the problem is, for security reasons, browsers do not allow this.. :'(

**So my question is :**

Is it possible when the drag and drop of a file, to upload it online during its use, so temporarily (because I use d3.json to recover the file and it allows me to recover json files online ..), and delete the online file at the end of its use, that is to say when closing the tab ??

Thanks you again for your help.

Comment: Why do you think you need the full path of the file?

Comment: JavaScript has full access to the _contents_ of any dropped file. What you want to do with those contents is completely up to you (process it, store it via AJAX, forget it...)

Comment: This smells very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you ultimately trying to achieve? If it is "Get access to the content of the file from client-side JS" then you don't need either the full path or to upload it to the server.

Comment: I'm trying to use d3.json when a user do a drag and drop of a file, but for use d3.json, i need the path of a file... :(

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi - Why do you think you need the path of the file to use it with d3? What API function are you trying to use the data with? I'll be very, very, very surprised if there isn't a version of it directly accepting the data rather than requiring a URL.

Comment: See this about the d3.json.. http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html if there any way to do it without the path of the file, it would be cool @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi Read T.J.Crowder's answer. You simply don't need `d3.json` here, just get the content and use it in the D3 code.

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi - If you're using `d3.json`, that gives you the parsed data from the file. The equivalent without the URL is to read it with a `FileReader` (as in my answer) and then parse it with `JSON.parse`. Then use the data exactly the way you would have if you'd read it with `d3.json`.

Comment: Thanks you ! @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the full path of the file to read its contents, and I'm certain d3 allows you to provide the data directly rather than reading it from "a file" (presumably that's really from a URL).

Simply read it with [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). For instance, in a `change` handler on `input type="file"`:

```
var file = theInput.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function() {
    // Use fr.result here, it's a string of the file's contents.
    // If it's JSON and you want the data in the form `d3.json` would have
    // provided it, do: `var data = JSON.parse(fr.result);`
    // and then use `data`.
};
fr.readAsText(file);
```

Live Example (just reading the file, not passing the data to d3):

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        console.log("Done");
        var pre = document.getElementById("output");
        pre.innerHTML = "";
        pre.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(fr.result)
        );
    };
    fr.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Error reading the file");
    };
    console.log("Reading...");
    fr.readAsText(file);
});
```

```css
pre {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
<hr>
Contents:
<pre id="output"></pre>
```